# Outlook Custom Forms: Sending User-Defined Fields in HTML

Tags: html, forms, vba, email, outlook

I've been struggling with this problem on and off for about 3 weeks now.  I've created an Outlook Custom Form which let's the user type in user-defined fields that I've created (let's call it **myField1**, **myField2**) along with the standard **To**, **CC**, **Subject**, **Date** fields.

The user fills out the form, clicks Send, instead of sending the custom form to the recipient, I want it to send (HTML?) of my user-defined fields and close the forms window.  This allows the recipient to view and print the fields entered and render readable in Outlook's Preview Pane.  Should I be exploring Outlook Region forms for what I'm trying to do??  The code I have right now doesn't generate errors, but it doesn't do anything! - the form sends as a form.  All I have access to is the Script Editor in Outlook 2010.  Very frustrating..

```
Function Item_Send()
'Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
'Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
'Dim mailItem As Outlook.mailItem

 Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

'Outlook.ApplicationClass _app = new Outlook.ApplicationClass();
'Outlook.Application olApp = (Outlook.Application)_app
'Outlook.NameSpace olNameSpace = _app.GetNamespace("MAPI")

'Create mail item
'Set objMail = myOlApp.GetItem(OlItemType.olMailItem)
 Set mailItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
'Outlook.mailItem mailItem = (Outlook.mailItem)olApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)

'With mailItem
   mailItem.Subject = item.Subject
   mailItem.Recipients.Add ("emails that I typed into the To: box")
   mailItem.Body = "This is the Body of an e-mail message"
  'Set body format to HTML
   mailItem.BodyFormat = 2
   mailItem.HTMLBody = "<HTML><H2>The body of this message will appear in HTML.</H2><BODY>Type the message text here. </BODY></HTML>"
   mailItem.Send()
'End With

'Set olMailItem = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You still need to generate the HTML markup containing the names and values of your custom fields.  All it takes is some judicious string building and you'll get the content you want.  You can access your custom fields via the MailItem. UserProperties.Find method.  Call that method for each of your fields and populate your HTML from the UserProperty.Name and .Value properties.

Comment: I find the body to be the easy part and will save it for last.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to include user property (associated with your custom controls) values into the message body. To get the job done you can handle the [ItemSend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865076.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event of the Application class which is fired whenever an Microsoft Outlook item is sent, either by the user through an Inspector (before the inspector is closed, but after the user clicks the Send button) or when the Send method for an Outlook item, such as MailItem, is used in a program. And I suppose you do that already, if so...

First, there is no need to create a new Outlook APplication instance in the ItemSend event handler:

```
Function Item_Send()
 'Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 Set olApp = Application
```

Use the `Application` property instead.

Second, the `ItemSend` event handler should look like the following one:

```
Private Sub myOlApp_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
```

There is no need to create a new MailItem instance, you have already got access to the existing item. The item being sent is passed as a parameter to the handler.

Comment: I totally redid the code and am getting stuck on passing the "To:" field that the user resolves on the custom form.  So I want to pass that "To:" field to my newMsg item, but it's simply just the user name that's getting passed.  Here's the problem: that user name is a rather generic one, so it is unable to resolve against the GAL.  Why can't I just pass the nice resolved recipient that the user had entered into my newMsg?  I assume now I have to deal with namespace and session?